# Gulp-Connect lists directory instead of showing index.html. Why?

Tags: gulp, gulp-connect

What is wrong with this gulp file? When it opens the browser, it does not show index.html. Instead, it lists the contents of 'dist', the directory containing index.html.

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); // Runs a local dev server
var open = require('gulp-open');

var config = {
    port: 9005,
    devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    paths: {
        html: './src/*.html',
        dist: './dist'
    }
};

//Start a local development server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: ['dist'],
        port: config.port,
        base: config.devBaseUrl,
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function () {
    gulp.src('dist/index.html')
        .pipe(open({
            uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/', 
            app: 'chrome' }));

});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'open', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to restrict the version of gulp-connect to `"gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",` The latest version works differently, but I do not know the correct syntax of the latest. When I tried the answer from the other poster, the page was displayed as expected, but the watch features did not work with it.

At the time of this writing, the current version is ^3.0.0.

I am on Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

[Update] As per @SteveDavis, this was fixed in version 3.2.0.

Comment: This tip was a lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: This problem was fixed in version 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Hello problem is with your open task you basically telling gulp to open dist directory instead of just index.html

Comment: I checked that. I am working from an example in PluralSight which does it this way. It was working at one point. Also, the example given on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-open) does it this way.

Comment: If I break with the documentation and append index.html, it shows up in the browser, but the 'watch' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To install the correct version of the gulp-connect plugin make sure you type in 
`npm install --save-dev gulp-connect@2.2.0` I had the same problem and changing back to that version solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure index.html is under src not psadmin project folder, so it can find it there when it executes

```
gulp.src(config.paths.html)
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist)
```

Comment: How is what you wrote different that what I wrote?